# How to change name for administrator login on azure sql server

Tags: azure-sql-database, management

I have myserver.database.windows.net with administrator login John.
I'd like to change it to Peter.
It is possible, if so, how ?

Alter which works with local sql server, doesn't work here

> ALTER LOGIN John WITH NAME=Peter

[image]

Comment: [This MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/df2aeea2-1f3a-4df1-8f22-327523f270f5/change-admin-username?forum=ssdsgetstarted) from 2009 says you just need to re-create the server - but I'm curious if there are any better solutions in the past 6 years.

Comment: Did you tried reset admin password

Comment: @TheGameiswar Sure. I can change the password, but that's not a problem. I'd like to rename Administrator Login.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So this may be an old question, but the problem is still relevant today.
The only way that you can alter the administrator of an Azure Sql Server, is to create a new SQL Server. Once the administrator has been set, you can reset their password, but not the name.

I just ran into this same issue and had the same #facepalm moment.

Comment: To just add oneadditional thing it does state in the documentation that the initial administration account created is `treated like the "sa" account` in the full version of SQL Server. So it would be assumed a restriction of not modifying it in this manner is there, although you can at least rename it on the full version.